# Git capital name change

Tags: git

I first created file name "Buypage" and did git commit.
After that I changed it as "BuyPage" but git didn't care about it.

Whenever i move between commits or change branches, the filename return to it's old name.

I tried to change it using the "git mv Buypage BuyPage" command, but it gave me an error.

`error fatal: bad source`
I found out through Googling that the above error is a problem that only occurs on Windows.
But i don't know how to solve it

Comment: Move from `Buypage` to `temp`, then from `temp` to `BuyPage`. That way you aren't ever doing a single step that changes only the upper/lower-case mix. Beware that this may create future problems whenever Git tries to do the same thing in a single step, rather than using this same two-step process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in a Windows CMD session:

```
git -c core.ignorecase=false mv -f Buypage BuyPage
```

Then check if `git status` shows:

```sh
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        renamed:    Buypage  -> BuyPage
```